# SQL Server : Complex Comparison & Update

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, sql-update

Long time user, first time poster.

If I was to script this in powershell, I'd probably be done by now. Im trying to expand my MSSQL skillset and could use your assistance. I've considered looping in MSSQL, which many sites have downplayed, and therefore am considering creating a function, but I seem stuck, and could use some help.

Problem:

1. Do a comparison of Value 1 in table 1, against values in table 2 and count the comparisons that return true. Compare if value 2 is equal or lesser than value 1, If true, add 1 to count
2. Update table 1 with the total count that returned true
3. Each new row in table 1 is unique, for which there are multiple records in table 2 for which the comparison can be done. Therefore each row in table 1, has a column value of null, for count, that needs to be updated

Expected Result for the following: In 2015, there are 4 records of type A in table 2. When I check the val, 50, in table 1 against those in table 2, only 3 records will return true if I do less than or equal to. So **3** would be added for Count in table 1

### Table1

```
| ID    Val     Year    Type    Count |
  1     50       2015    A
  1     60       2015    B
  1     75       2015    C
  2     90       2015    A
```

### Table2

```
| ID    Val     Year    Type    |
  1     40       2015    A
  1     50       2015    A
  1     45       2015    A
  1     90       2015    A
```

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you would include an example data for both of the tables and expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're doing your comparison, but it sounds like you're looking for a subquery.

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET [Count] = 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 
    WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
    AND Table2.Val <= Table1.Val
)
```

Comment: Is might be necessary to limit the update to only rows with `[Count] is null`. Hard to tell from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can use INNER or CROSS JOINS.

```
UPDATE T1
SET [Count] = COUNT(*) FROM 
Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 
ON T1.Type = T2.Type AND T1.Year = T2.Year 
WHERE T1.Val>=T2.Val
```